# ¿Como hacer que Firebase me reporte los cambios SOLO cuando le doy click a un boton? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo un problema con el Firebase en Android Studio.

Yo tengo en mi interfaz  2 botones, uno que se llama "Subir Data" y otro que se llama "Obtener Data". Cuando yo le doy al botón "Subir Data" sube la data perfectamente al Firebase, sin embargo, cuando le doy al botón "Obtener Data" yo programe que me  genere un reporte PDF de toda la información del Firebase,y en la primera vez que le doy al boton "Obtener Data" si me da lo que quiero, pero cuando otra vez le doy al boton "Subir Data" sube la informacion al Firebase, entonces se actualiza el Firebase y me muestra sin querer el PDF antes creado(ESTE ES MI PROBLEMA), tiene sentido, ya que se actualizo el Firebase y por tanto debe mostrar el PDF ya que su codigo esta dentro del :

```
"ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() { @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {"
```

este codigo esta dentro del boton "ObtenerData".

Que puedo hacer??

Gracias :)

```
  public void boton3_basededato(View view){
    templatePDF.openDocument();
    templatePDF.addParagraph(shortText);
    templatePDF.addParagraph(longText);
    DatabaseReference mRootReference;
    mRootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRootReference.child("Usuario").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int cont=0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String todo=snapshot.getValue().toString();

                if(todo.contains("{")){cont++;}

            }
            int j=0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {  //lo que esta despues de los ":" obtiene los datos alfanumericos y el snapshot.getValue obtiene los demas valores que estan dentro

                userPojo user = snapshot.getValue(userPojo.class); // que me traiga los valores que solo estan declarados en el userPojo.class


                templatePDF.addParagraph(user.getCodigo());
                templatePDF.addParagraph(user.getPlano());
                templatePDF.addParagraph(user.getElemento());
                templatePDF.addParagraph(String.valueOf(user.getSlump()));
                templatePDF.addParagraph(user.getComentario());
                templatePDF.addParagraph(espacios);

                j++;
                if(j==cont){
                   templatePDF.closeDocument();
                   templatePDF.viewBasededatos();
                }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, evita colocar el código como imagen ya que complica que alguien pueda ayudarte es mejor que edites tu pregunta, coloques tu código y lo formatees adecuadamente utilizando el botón **{}**. Adicional pasate por la página [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esto `addValueEventListener` por esto `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` en tu metodo **boton3_basededato**

```
mRootReference.child("Usuario").addListenerForSingleValueEvent...
```

### addValueEventListener

Esto quiere decir que estas todo el tiempo escuchando a cambios bajo tu referencia `.child("Usuario")` , por lo que si cambia cualquier cosa de la misma el metodo `boton3_basededato` se va a ejecutar. Lo que pasa es que cuando apretas el boton para generar el PDF, atachas un listener a esa referencia, y por cada escritura a esa referencia se esta lanzando tu listener que genera el PDF.

### addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Solo se va a lanzar la vez que apretes el boton y luego va a parar de escuchar a esa referencia por cambios, por lo que se ejecutaria solo 1 vez la request. De este modo, cuando apretes para generar el PDF va a generarlo una vez con los datos dentro de la referencia y luego no lo va a hacer de nuevo si subes datos a no ser que vuelvas a apretar el boton para volver a obtener datos de esa referencia.

Comment: Hola, podrias ayudarme con esta pregunta porfavor: 
           https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212744/como-traigo-datos-que-no-se-repitan-de-firebase-en-android-studio