# Como traigo datos que no se repitan de Firebase en Android Studio?

Tags: java, firebase

Hola tengo un problema con el Firebase,estoy creando una app que es como una aplicacion de toma de datos donde el usuario pincha en SI o NO y yo debo hacer un grafico estadistico de cuantos tienen SI en diferentes campos como Comentario, Plano,etc. pero como el usuario puede editar algunos campos dentro de paquete(Por ejemplo editar a un "NO" el campo "Comentario"), se crearia otro paquete de codigo C1 con un "NO" en "comentario" pero aun estaria el paquete anterior que tenia el "Si" en su "comentario" y yo al momento de hacer la grafica estadistica tendria que usar el ultimo valor ingresado y pues el Firebase me lee todos los datos sin importar si es repetido o no y me daria datos erroneos

Yo hize un ciclo for para poder recorrer todos los campos pero no se como quitarle los repetidos. Gracias

```html
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuario").orderByChild("Comentario").equalTo("Si");
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    cnt = 0;
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String value = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                        tv.setText(value);
                        if (value.contains("Codigo=C")) {
                            NcomentariosC++;
                        }
                        if (value.contains("Codigo=V")) {
                            NcomentariosV++;
                        }
                        if (value.contains("Codigo=P")) {
                            NcomentariosP++;
                        }
                        cnt++;
                    }

                    Intent intento = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataGraficos.class);
                    intento.putExtra("NcomentCol", NcomentariosCol);

                    intento.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intento);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. Tu pregunta no es clara en cuanto a lo que quieres. ¿Quieres únicamente los registros con `Codigo=C1` y `Comentario=Si` pero sin repetidos? ¿Quieres con no importa qué `Codigo` y `Comentario=Si`, pero sin repetidos? Por otra parte, yo diría que la estructura de tu modelo de datos no está pensada al estilo `Firebase`. Te obliga a recorrer todos los nodos para obtener una información que podría estar accesible de un modo más óptimo en otra parte (por ej. un nodo que guarde usuarios/comentarios). Además, en vez de `Si/No` sería bueno usar booleanos `TRUE/FALSE`...

Comment: ... creo que sería muy importante **leer y entender** lo que la documentación explica en el apartado [**Estructura tu base de datos**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?hl=es). Firebase en muchos aspectos funciona de una forma totalmente distinta a la que estamos acostumbrados, sobre todo en la forma de organizar el modelo de datos.

Comment: Hola, si ya edite mi pregunta, ahora esta mas entendible, lo que pasa es que cada dato del cada paquete se relaciona, mira el Codigo C1, significa que C es Columna, entonces al pedir en mi pregunta "Que todos los "Si" de las "Columnas" es como decir tambien "Los SI de las C1 o C2 o C3, etc" - Y mi app es como una aplicacion de toma de datos donde el usuario pincha en SI o NO y yo debo hacer un grafico estadistico de cuantos tienen SI, pero como puedes editar algunos campos dentro de paquete, se crearia otro paquete de codigo C1 y se repetiria y yo quiero solo el ultimo :)

Answer (score 0):

> yo al momento de hacer la grafica estadistica tendria que usar el
>   ultimo valor ingresado y pues el Firebase me lee todos los datos sin
>   importar si es repetido o no y me daria datos erroneos

Proba agregando a tu query que te traiga solo el ultimo elemento agregado

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuario").orderByChild("Comentario").equalTo("Si").limitToLast(1);
```

Comment: Hola Gaston, queria primero agradecerte por leer mi pregunta, no habia escuchado del limitToLast, sin embargo  me dio de resultado solo el "1" en "NcomentariosPlaca++" debido a que en mi firebase tengo primero unos 7 paquetes de valores que son Columnas , luego unas cuantas de vigas y luego unas cuantas de placas, (subi los datos al firebase asi para entender mejor) y con el limitToLast por lo que veo solo cogio el ultimo valor de mi lista que seria la ultima Placa y da un "1" al correr. Se puede ordenar de varias formas ,pero ¿como hacer para que no ponga en la lista a informacion repetida?

Answer (score 0):

"se crearia otro paquete de codigo C1 con un "NO" en "comentario" pero aun estaria el paquete anterior que tenia el "Si" en su "comentario" y yo al momento de hacer la grafica estadistica tendria que usar el ultimo valor ingresado"

Sino quieres usar el "paquete" anterior para que lo guardas? lo usas en otro momento? No puedes simplemente actualizar el "sí" por un "no" en vez de crear otra entrada?

Otra cosa que no entiendo es por qué todas esas entradas están en nodo "usuario", tenés lo mismo para cada usuario? todas esas entradas son del mismo usuario?

Por ahí dejando un ejemplo de qué resultados querrías obtener pueda ayudarte. Saludos!